# How to mock Spring Boot repository while using Axon framework

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mockito, axon

I'm currently trying to implement some app using Axon framework and Spring Boot and I need to write unit tests for one of the sagas.
In this saga, aside form axon's functionalities I also use spring boot repository, which I need to mock for the test.

The problem is, repository is not being injected - it's always null.
I would REALLY appreciate any help in this matter.

Find issued classes below:

Saga:

```
@Slf4j
@Saga
@Service
public class ValidationSaga {  

    @Autowired
    private transient CommandGateway commandGateway;
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    private String correlationId;
    private String emp1Code;
    private String emp2Code;
    private String emp1Id;
    private String emp2Id;
    private String emp3Id;
    private String emp3Code;

    @StartSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "correlationId")
    public void on(NewMatchingDocumentAggregate.MatchingSubmittedEvent event) {


        log.debug(">>>    HANDLING IN SAGA");
        log.debug(">>> REPO: ", employeeRepository); //At this point repo is null

        this.correlationId = event.getCorrelationId();
        this.emp1Code= event.getEmp1Code();
        this.emp2Code= event.getEmp2Code();
        this.emp1Id= event.getEmp1Id();
        this.emp2Id= event.getEmp2Id();
        this.emp3Id= event.getEmp3Id();
        this.emp3Code= event.getEmp3Code();

        if(!employeeRepository.existsById(event.getEmp1Id())) {
            employeeRepository.save(EmployeeEntity.builder()
                .employeeCode(event.getEmp1Code())
                .employeeName(null)
                .isActive(true)
                .removeFromRole(false)
                .build());
        }

        if(!employeeRepository.existsById(event.getEmp2Id())) {
            employeeRepository.save(EmployeeEntity.builder()
                    .employeeCode(event.getEmp2Code())
                    .employeeName(null)
                    .isActive(true)
                    .removeFromMentorRole(false)
                    .build());
        }
        log.debug(">>> > before gateway");

        commandGateway.send(new NewMatchingDocumentAggregate.ApplyContextCommand(
                this.correlationId, this.emp1Code, this.emp2Code, this.emp1Id, this.emp2Id,
                this.emp3Id, this.emp3Code));
    }

    @EndSaga
    @SagaEventHandler(associationProperty = "correlationId")
    public void on(NewMatchingDocumentAggregate.MatchingDefinedEvent event) {
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Slf4j
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ValidationSagaTest {

    @Mock
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    @InjectMocks
    private ValidationSaga validationSaga;

    private FixtureConfiguration fixture;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        fixture = new SagaTestFixture<>(ValidationSaga.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldSendApplyContextCommand_whenEmployeesExists_givenSomeEvent() {

        val correlationId = "correlationId";
        val emp1Code = "emp1Code ";
        val emp2Code = "emp2Code ";
        val emp1Id = "emp1Id ";
        val emp2Id = "emp2Id ";
        val emp3Id = "emp3Id ";
        val emp3Code = "emp3Code ";

        when(employeeRepository.existsById(emp1Id)).thenReturn(true);
        when(employeeRepository.existsById(emp2Id)).thenReturn(true);

        fixture.givenNoPriorActivity()
                .whenAggregate(correlationId)
                .publishes(new NewMatchingDocumentAggregate.MatchingSubmittedEvent(correlationId, emp1Code,
                        emp2Code, emp1Id, emp2Id, emp3Id, emp3Code))
                .expectActiveSagas(1)

                .expectDispatchedCommands(new NewMatchingDocumentAggregate.ApplyContextCommand(correlationId,
                        emp1Code, emp2Code, emp1Id, emp2Id, emp3Id, emp3Code));

    }
```

Comment: Apart from you actual question, I'd like to suggest to make *any* services in your Saga implementation `transient`. A Saga is a serialized object in Axon and you definitely don't want to pull your `EmployeeRepository` through the serializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Saga` in Axon is not a Spring managed Bean, although the possibility to use the `@Autowired` annotation to wire Beans in it does make it seem so.
To wire Beans in your Saga, the framework uses an implementation of the `ResourceInjector`, more specifically the `SpringResourceInjector`.

Now that info does not necessarily solve you problem, but probably does give you a hint you need to do something specific to inject mocked services in your Saga. To be able to use your mocked services, you need to call the `SagaTestFixture#registerResource(Object)` function, where the provided `Object` is your mocked Service.

I'd suggest the `setUp()` to be the ideal place to register those resources for your situation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Works like a charm now! Really, really thank You for helping me out :)